# Update a table based in another table

Tags: excel

I have a table with information from my employees that different people are working simultaneously. This means that if someone is hired,fired,new position, etc they have to update it. Something like this:

[image]

Then I have another table which I will calculate some courses that they performed during the week based on the information from the employees table. So, I just copy and paste the information above in my other table and start filling the courses cell. However I would like to automated it (instead of having to copy and paste always). My idea is that if someone changes anything, the information that the person just changed is going to directly appear in my other table without having to copy and paste.

I tried to simply add the cell that I wanted (like: employeestable!A2) but should be definitely a smarter way to perform it.

Can you please help me?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you can use Power Query for this. In Power Query you can link tables together.
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2018/11/14/excel-join-tables-power-query/

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).